# Tab control not resetting to first page when filling last field

Tags: ms-access, tabcontrol

I'm fairly new to microsoft access and i'm currently designing a database for my company but I'm having some trouble trying to get the tab control to work properly. The problem is whenever it navigates through all the pages, when it reaches the last field to fill in, it goes to the next record but stays in the last page, it doesn't 'reset' back to the first page so it follows a logical order.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?  Can we see your code?

Comment: In your form's On Current event, `SetFocus` to the first page of your tab control.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, I've tried working with the [Enter] event in order to reset the focus to the first field of the tabs. There is no code, i've been using macros so far. I've tried the browse to, go to page, go to control macros to try to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @HansUp I'll try finding code for setting focus.

Comment: I got how to make it go back to the first page, but how do it make it go to the first page of the next record. That's what's giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HansUp offered a good suggestion in his comment, but you may not want to unconditionally `SetFocus` the first tab in `OnCurrent` because that could cause the tab focus to switch as users navigate from one record to another using the record selector buttons. There could be cases where the users might find that annoying.

Instead, you might want to use the `LostFocus` event of the final field to manipulate a flag that would allow `OnCurrent` to `SetFocus` the first tab when the user moves to a new record by "falling off the end" of the previous record, but leave the tab focus alone if the user is just stepping through the records.

Comment: Got it, I used 2 macros to make the user navigate automatically to a new record once they entered the last field in the tab. It was actually pretty simple, I first used the macro [go to control] first page in the event -lost focus- and then added another macro [go to record] -next- to make it run to the other record. Thank you for your time, I appreciate your help!